# Update List Using Column And Textboxes

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, fast-for-sharepoint

```
        SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Web;
        SPList list = web.Lists["MyList"];
        SPListItem item = list.Items[0];

        item["Title"] = TextBox_Name.Text;

        item.SystemUpdate(false);
        list.Update();
```

I have written this code that works well, but I have more columns and text that I want to update how can i solve this?

Answer (score 1):

I dont know if this is what your looking for but from what i understand you want to do the following?

```
    SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Web;
    SPList list = web.Lists["MyList"];
    SPListItem item = list.Items[0];

    item["Title"] = TextBox_Title.Text;
    item["Name"] = TextBox_Name.Text;
    item["Address"] = TextBox_Address.Text;
    item["Age"] = TextBox_Age.Text;

    item.SystemUpdate(false);
    list.Update();
```

I think thats what you mean?

hope it helps :)